# Am I being blackmailed by sugar daddy or is this legit?

Tags: scams, sugar-daddy

I found out about how well sugar babies were getting treated so I thought I’d try it on for size.

Something went wrong and my sugar daddy threatened me saying his friend was an FBI agent, he had my address and would be coming after me. He even said that he pitied my life, told me I’d ruin my life in prison. I then received a message from someone who said they were in fact an FBI agent for my sugar daddy and then proceeded to tell me that he had my address.

My sugar daddy never sent me any money but said I would be getting it Monday. It’s Monday and I haven’t seen a penny. Can he legally do anything to me?

Comment: What did the scammer want from you?

Comment: He wanted my bank logins and when I refused he began to threaten me claiming he had put $7,000 in my account.

Comment: Yeah, you did the right thing not giving bank info, people can send money through legitimate methods if they want to. If you did get money erroneously, you'd contact your bank, not compromise your bank security. Also, an actual FBI agent could contact you through a normal channel rather than threaten you online.

Comment: Did the "FBI Agent" (=scammer under a different name) actually _tell_ you your address, or – as is much more likely – just say "_I know your address_"? Anyone can _say_ they know something.

Comment: *I found out about how well sugar babies were getting treated* - looking at [the questions about sugar daddies on this website](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sugar-daddy), most so-called "sugar babies" don't get treated very well. But our view of that scene might be a bit skewed because those who actually find a rich but lonely guy willing to support them in exchange for some sexual favors would have little reason to post here.

Comment: You said you declined to give them your bank account info (good choice) but have you actually shared any personal information with them already?  Did you tell them your address, for example, or any other information they might have been able to find your address with?  It's unlikely that they're actually going to show up at your door, but good to know how realistic the threat is.  If any money *does* show up in your account, as Hart CO said, you talk to your bank, not to these jokers.  Real FBI agents don't warn you that they're coming ahead of time.

Answer (score 11):

Real FBI agents don't send you emails, they show up at your door - probably about 6 AM - with drawn guns. Ignore the scammer.

FWIW, I would bet that the supposed "FBI agent" is just the scammer using a different email address.

And just a quibble about language.  What this person is trying to do to you is extortion, not blackmail.  Blackmail is when you pay a person not to reveal things you want to keep secret.  If a real FBI agent tried to threaten you at a friend's request, you'd be in a position to blackmail them :-)

Answer (score 5):

he is trying to scam you.

Do not give him *any* info, better stop answering him.
His threats are baseless; if you ignore him, he'll disappear.