# What do I do if a sugar daddy who sent me money is asking for money back or threatening me with FBI asking he needs a $1000 to pay off his workers?

Tags: scams, sugar-daddy

I’m confused on what to do. Recently, I was talking to a guy who came to me first on Snapchat wanting me to be his sugar baby and I agreed. Long story short, he told me he would be giving me an allowance of 5,000 and never did, but tried to send me money. I kind of felt off about the whole deal and told him I wasn’t interested anymore and kept begging me back. I didn’t care about his money to proceed, especially since I never met him, so he apparently sent 1000 to me. I called him on FaceTime to see him in person and he turned out to be someone else, the guy looked like he was from Africa. I was like "WTF?" and he keeps trying to claim it was his chef who answered? That doesn’t make any sense so I blocked him. He keeps trying to contact me and threatening me he wants 1000 as he has to pay off his workers who pissed him off.
They’re trying to threaten me with the FBI because I won’t send their 1000 back.

If he was a sugar daddy, he should have enough money to pay them off, not ask me for the money. I’ve FaceTimed him but he won’t answer, claiming he’s working and can’t answer. Yet, he has the time to text me. I find this bullshit, but I need to know — is this legit or bullshit?

Comment: Just a scammer doing scammy things.

Comment: Search here for sugar daddy scam, this is clearly one.  The important thing is that 1,000 is not your money.  Do not send it to anyone, but also do not spend it as it will almost certainly disappear soon.  The FBI will not be involved.

Comment: Related: https://money.stackexchange.com/q/128025 and https://money.stackexchange.com/q/139642 and https://money.stackexchange.com/q/121854 and https://money.stackexchange.com/q/131195 and https://money.stackexchange.com/q/134828

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: maybe it's time for a Community Wiki about sugar daddy scams.

Comment: @QuoraFeans Do you mean a CW question that lists all sugar-related questions, perhaps in various sections?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: yes, exactly. Maybe it should be about scams in general. These questions are common, and the answer seems to be the same. (yes, it is a scam)

Comment: @QuoraFeans There are only 63 sugar-related questions and they are quite similar. It's not too bad yet.

Answer (score 3):

It’s all just a scam. The last thing a scammer wants to do is actually get law enforcement involved, so in answer to your question of “what should I do” - delete, block, move on. And don’t enter into these kinds of arrangements in future with someone you haven’t met in person.

Answer (score 2):

This smells like money laundering.

That is usually the case when someone gave you money and now they want you to send the money to someone else. Was that what happened?

If it's dirty money, you'd get in trouble for it.