# Sugar Daddy is Threatening to Report Me To FBI

Tags: sugar-daddy

I recently got involved with someone Over the internet and I asked him if he wanted me to be his sugar baby. Long story short he agreed and sent me money to be his sugar baby. I told him I was going to go and see him but I lied because I didn’t know this man. So he said he contacted the fbi and said if I didn’t send the money back he was coming after me. But then he tells me you can still come see me if you want. So we started talking and I told him I was 17 which I’m not I’m 18 but he said he would let me keep the money and that we were ok. Now he’s saying oh the FBI contacted me and you need to send it back before they take action because what you did was illegal. So I asked him for screenshots and the email and he won’t give it to me. I seriously don’t know what to do. Should I send it back or keep it. I’ve already invested time into him and all. Also with me telling him I was 17 he was ok with it and he’s like 42 years older than me. He also told me he liked younger women and was ok with me being younger. What should I do?

Comment: Do you actually think a 59 year old guy would want his friends / family / work know that he was looking at an 18 year old.

Comment: So I can’t get introuble?

Comment: No but I also threatened him and said I would go to the police and he told me to go

Comment: Ignore him.  These type of petty things would not be in FBI's radar.

Comment: Ok thank you so much.

Comment: "because what you did was illegal": what did you do that's allegedly illegal?  If the money was *explicitly* for *travel expenses*, then you probably committed fraud.  If it was "here's your sugar baby money", then you committed nothing except the bad judgement of wanting to be a sugar baby.  I'd be **Very Disappointed** if you were my daughter.

Comment: It wasn’t for travel expenses he said he had a friend that would pay a girl to be his sugar baby and she would come see him every weekend and stay the whole weekend. I told him I was coming to do that but in reality I wasn’t. And he said that he reported me because I told him I was coming and I didn’t and he said that was what the money was for so I would come see him. But in my eyes the money for was being the sugar baby. We had talked after the fact and I told him I wasn’t going to be able to come and he was ok with that. He said I could keep the money and continue being his sugar baby.

Comment: " I also threatened him and said I would go to the police" This may be extortion. Don't do that. But in this case the guy is not going to take you to court and make his own misbehavior public. Just never answer his emails/texts/phone calls again.

Comment: Ignore it, when two shady people (you and him) make a shady deal, involving the authorities is nothing more than a hollow bluff. You should quit this whole "Sugar..." business. You are asking to get scammed.

Comment: @Amanda, the FBI is not involved here. He thinks that mentioning them will make you panic. If the FBI were involved, would they be more interested in the money or the 60 year old guy hitting on an underage young woman? He is asking for the money back because he wants you to launder this money for him. He sent you "dirty" money (stolen, a bad check, or just trying to hide where it came from). If you send him money out of your bank account, you are giving him back "clean" money. Once the banks catch up his transfer to you will be reversed and he will have your money. Don't contact him again!

Comment: Please check all the sugar baby/daddy scams on this site to see what could potentially happen.

Answer (score -2):

As I understand it, he paid you money so that you will be his sugar baby and/or meet him. You took his money but refused to be his sugar baby and/or meet him. Therefore you are in [breach of contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breach_of_contract). It would be a verbal contract, but verbal contracts are still contracts, and he can contact law enforcement.

What happens next is not for me to say. I would guess that a judge would find you guilty, and the likely penalty would be a fine, but I am not a lawyer. You might want to speak to a lawyer or at least ask on the Law.SE.